# pushState method doesnt work

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm trying to change URL without reloading a page, using a `window.history.pushState` method, but it's not working as I want. For example I have an address: `localhost:1234/jobs` and I would like change this to `localhost:1234/jobs?jobId=1#update`, so I tried do this by my own method:

```
changeAddress(jobId){    
    window.history.pushState(null, "Job update", "/jobs?jobId=" + jobId + "#update");
};
```

But it's not working, this method is making good address only for one second and it backs to old value. 
I made a method which should activate after url change -

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    console.log(window.location.href);            
});
```

But nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Ok, so maybe after example from my code everything will be more clearly. 
I have an element in .jsp file:

```
<i class="fas fa-edit fa-fw"
                       data-tooltip="tooltip"
                       title="Edit this job"
                       ng-click="goJobModal(job.id);$event.stopPropagation()"></i>
```

After pressing this button, method goJobModal should execute:

```
$scope.goJobModal = function (jobId) {
      if(jobId){
          window.history.pushState=(null, "Updating job, "/jobs?jobId=" + jobId + "#update");          
      } else {
          window.history.pushState(null, "Creating job", "/jobs#create");              
      }
    };
```

This method is only changing url using a `window.history.pushState`, then popstate event should be triggered:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    console.log(window.location.href);
    $scope.makeActionWithHashParam();
});
```

But it's not.

Comment: Not reproducible..

Comment: maybe your code is triggered too often or nothing at all

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. The address changing is probably because you are doing something to cause the browser to navigate *after* running that function.

Comment: Ok I added example from my code